# XAML layout changes not updating on build

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 project that I am working on in VS2012.
Its been doing this for a while, but I haven't got to the bottom of it.

If you make any changes to the XAML, like moving a grid, and then deploy it to the phone.
But the changes are not applied when the viewing the app on the phone, the grid hasnt moved. The only way to apply it, it is uninstall the app from the phone and deploy again, or delete the 'Release' folder which it has built and build again.

C# code changes are deployed ok though.

Comment: Does it work if you *Rebuild* the project? Is the problem for this specific project or does it happen with any project?

Comment: I have the same problem so I answer: If I "new rebuild" the project it's working. Not with autorebuild on run (F5) or normal rebuild (F6). This problem is specific to my current project I created yesterday, usually it was working just fine for WP8 and VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

Does the project name contain (or the folder it is in) any spaces?

In my case, removing spaces solved the problem.